# "Invalid element (ptype)" error coming in Janus when a new participan join to the video room

Tags: webrtc, janus, janus-gateway

I am developing a video room component when a new peer joins to the video room there is an error coming and unable to receive remote video

`[ERR] [plugins/janus_videoroom.c:janus_videoroom_handler:4007] Invalid element (type)`

how to fix this issue?

Comment: did you find solution for this? I am also getting same error and stuck now,

Comment: add STUN and TURN server and update the latest version of JANUS

Comment: Thanks Shihabudheen! Is there any document / sample / link you can point me